Return the contents of an EXEC from a stored procedure
I have the following which returns a string produced by the EXEC in the output when running the stored procedure directly but I need to pass this string back to a calling stored procedure.
This stored procedure will be called from within the main loop of another stored procedure, and I need the text produced by the EXEC to be stored in a variable on the calling procedure.
I have used the EXEC sp_executesql command before but don't know if this applies here.
Output:
target.JOBID = source.JOBID And target.stackid = source.stackid And target.testtypeid = source.testtypeid And target.sampledparameter = source.sampledparameter And 

Completion time: 2024-06-26T16:42:29.4295301+01:00

This is the stored procedure I need to return the output of the EXEC:
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLinkCriteria]
    @TableName nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

    SET @sql = '
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''JOBID'' )
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria = ''target.JOBID = source.JOBID And '' END          
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''stackid'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.stackid = source.stackid And '' END     
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''testtypeid'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.testtypeid = source.testtypeid And '' END   
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''colid'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.colid = source.colid And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''runid'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.runid = source.runid And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''lineid'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.lineid = source.lineid And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''component'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.component = source.component And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''sampledparameter'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.sampledparameter = source.sampledparameter And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''parameter'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.parameter = source.parameter And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''filename'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.filename = source.filename And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''runtype'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.runtype = source.runtype And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''parentmetalparameter'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.parentmetalparameter = source.parentmetalparameter And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''metal'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.metal = source.metal And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''gassampled'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.gassampled = source.gassampled And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''sampledgas'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.sampledgas = source.sampledgas And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''purpose'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.purpose = source.purpose And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''isblank'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.isblank = source.isblank And '' END
            PRINT @linkcriteria;
            ';
    EXEC ('DECLARE @linkcriteria nvarchar(max);' + @Sql)
END


No sure what you are trying to accomplish here but be warned, this procedure is open to sql injection.

I'm creating a list of dynamic table linking assignments that will be put into a MERGE command that is used to take raw updated date from a C# program and merge it into an existing database. It has to be done this way because there are no unique ID index fields. sql injection isn't a concern at this point as it's far from going live. That would be tied down sometime in the future if it ever works!

Both returning the value to the calling procedure and avoiding SQL injection come down to using output parameters, both on the stored procedure and on sp_executesql.  Try something like this:
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLinkCriteria]
    @TableName nvarchar(max),
    @rv nvarchar(max) output
AS

/*
  declare @rv nvarchar(max)
  exec GetLinkCriteria @tablename='foo', @rv=@rv output
  print @rv
*/
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

    SET @sql = '
            DECLARE @linkcriteria nvarchar(max) = '''';

            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = ''JOBID'' )
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria = ''target.JOBID = source.JOBID And '' END          
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = ''stackid'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.stackid = source.stackid And '' END     
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = ''testtypeid'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.testtypeid = source.testtypeid And '' END   
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = ''colid'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.colid = source.colid And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = ''runid'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.runid = source.runid And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = ''lineid'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.lineid = source.lineid And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = ''component'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.component = source.component And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = ''sampledparameter'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.sampledparameter = source.sampledparameter And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = ''parameter'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.parameter = source.parameter And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = ''filename'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.filename = source.filename And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = ''runtype'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.runtype = source.runtype And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = ''parentmetalparameter'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.parentmetalparameter = source.parentmetalparameter And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = ''metal'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.metal = source.metal And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = ''gassampled'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.gassampled = source.gassampled And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = ''sampledgas'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.sampledgas = source.sampledgas And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = ''purpose'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.purpose = source.purpose And '' END
            IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = ''isblank'')
                BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += ''target.isblank = source.isblank And '' END
            --print(@linkcriteria)
            set @rv = @linkcriteria;
            ';
    --print @sql
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@tableName nvarchar(max), @rv nvarchar(max) output', @tableName=@tableName, @rv = @rv output
END


I made these changes to the GetLinkCriteria procedure but when I run it directly it still displays the text when the "exec GetLinkCriteria @tablename='StackDetails', @rv=@rv output" command is run and doesn't show anything for "PRINT @rv". This means that when I try to call this from the main procedure it holds the contents of the EXEC text and not the intended output.

Although the text being brought into the main procedure is what I expected it to be.

I got this working based on what you said, thanks.

I have fixed this based on what was provided by David.
I just had to set the return value 'rv' to my @linkcriteria variable
and remove the PRINT statement that was there for testing.
E.g.
            SET @rv = @linkcriteria
            --PRINT @linkcriteria;
            ';
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@LinkTableName nvarchar(max), @rv nvarchar(max) output', @LinkTableName=@LinkTableName, @rv=@rv output

